# Find unique strings in C++, and generate associated lookup vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, unique

A have a vector of strings in c++:

```
vector<string> myVect = {"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", "foo", "A", "foo"};
```

How can I convert this to a vector of integers, so that each integer uniquely corresponds to a string in `myVect`?
i.e. I would like a vector

```
out = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 3}
```

In addition, I would like a vector of the unique strings, each position corresponding to the number in `out`:

```
uniqueStrings = {"A", "B", "C", "foo"}
```

So far I have the following:

```
  vector<string> uniqueStrings;   // stores list of all unique strings
  vector<int> out(myVect.size());

  for (int i = 0; i < myVect.size(); ++i)
  {

    // seeing if this string has been encountered before
    bool assigned = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < uniqueStrings.size(); ++j)
      if (!myVect.at(i).compare( uniqueStrings.at(j) ))
      {
        out.at(i) = j;
        assigned = true;
        break;
      }

    // if not, add new example to uniqueStrings
    if (!assigned)
    {
      uniqueStrings.push_back(myVect.at(i));
      out.at(i) = uniqueStrings.size();
    }

  }
```

This works, but surely there must be a better way?

Comment: Is this homework? As a hint, you might consider looking at `std::map` or something similar to associate a string with a number.

Comment: Not homework, I'm trying to compute fecture vectors for input to a machine learning algorithm. I'm used to the brevity of MATLAB, where the whole of the above code would be `[uniqueStrings, ~, out] = unique(myVect)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more or less complete example of how you might use a `std::map<>` to maintain a mapping of unique strings to an integer ID:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


// a simple functor type that makes it easier to dump the contents of a 
//  container of simple values or a container of std::pair
struct dump
{
    template <typename K, typename V>
    void operator()( typename std::pair<K,V> const& x)
    {
        cout << x.first << " ==> " << x.second << endl;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void operator()( T const& x)
    {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
};



#define NUM_ELEM(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))

char const* data[] = {"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", "foo", "A", "foo"};

int main() {
    // intialize the data set
    vector<string> myVect( data, data + NUM_ELEM(data));

    cout << "dump of initial data set" << endl << endl;
    for_each( myVect.begin(), myVect.end(), dump());

    map<string,size_t> uniqueStrings;   // stores collection of all unique strings

    for (vector<string>::iterator i = myVect.begin(); i != myVect.end(); ++i) {
        // I'm using uniqueStrings.size() as a convenience here...
        // I just needed something to generate  unique ID's easily,
        // it might not be appropriate to use size() for your ID's in real life

        // this will insert the new mapping if there's not already one 
        uniqueStrings.insert( make_pair(*i, uniqueStrings.size()));
    }


    cout << endl << endl<< "dump of uniqueStrings" << endl << endl;
    for_each( uniqueStrings.begin(), uniqueStrings.end(), dump());

    // I'm not sure if you'd need this `out` vector anymore - you can probably just
    //  use the `uniqueStrings` map directly for this information (but that would
    //  depend on your specific needs)

    vector<int> out;
    for (vector<string>::iterator i = myVect.begin(); i != myVect.end(); ++i) {
        out.push_back( uniqueStrings[*i]);
    }

    cout << endl << endl << "dump of `out` vector" << endl << endl;
    for_each( out.begin(), out.end(), dump());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep pushing them in a map where the string is the key and the value corresponds to the id of each string. Then the values of your map will uniquely correspond to the strings and the keys will be the unique strings.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/).

```
# include <set>
...
set <string> uniqueStrings;
...
for (int i = 0; i < myVect.size(); ++i)
{
    uniqueStrings.insert(myVect[i]);
}
```